# mapply Error when trying to apply a formula to two columns

Tags: r

I am getting an error when I run the following code

```
 TransPSnoNA <- mapply(noNA,x = TransPerSend1[,2],y = TransPerSend1[,3])
```

noNA is a function that replaces NA's with 0 I wrote which works if I use an sapply on one column.

```
noNA <- function(x) if(is.na(x)==TRUE){x=0}else{x}
```

The sample data set looks like this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1    2    3
2    NA    3
2    4    NA
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in (function (x)  : unused argument (y = dots[[2]][[1]])
```

I have tried to set `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` and this does not work either. Any help?

As far as I understand, mapply allows me to use a function (in my case noNA) on two columns in a data frame at once. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hi, I have added the info you required

Comment: I added that in the edit as well. noNA is a function that replaces NA's with 0 I wrote which works if I use an sapply on one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work

```
 TransPerSend1[2:3] <- t(mapply(function(x,y) replace(c(x,y),
            is.na(c(x,y)), 0), TransPerSend1[,2], TransPerSend1[,3]))
```

But, I think this can be better solved

```
TransPerSend1[,2:3][is.na(TransPerSend1[,2:3])] <- 0
```

Or even

```
 TransPerSend1[2:3] <- lapply(TransPerSend1[,2:3],
                     function(x) replace(x, is.na(x),0))
```

#### Update

Regarding the error message, the `noNA` function had a single argument. Suppose, if it was:

```
 noNA <- function(x,...) if(is.na(x)==TRUE){x=0}else{x}
```

it still evaluates the `x`

```
 mapply(noNA,x = TransPerSend1[,2],y = TransPerSend1[,3])
 #[1] 2 0 4
```

The reason for `t` is because, the code I used gives an output with 3 columns and 2 rows, which should be transposed as to get 2 columns as intended.

```
 #      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #[1,]    2    0    4
 #[2,]    3    3    0
```

#### data

```
TransPerSend1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L), Col2 = c(2L, NA, 4L), 
 Col3 = c(3L, 3L, NA)), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your help. Your code worked. But do you know why I was getting that initial error? did I use mapply incorrectly? And why do you have a t in front of your mapply?

Comment: Thanks again for the update. so here is a new code I made that didnt give me the error but stopped replacing the NA's. Can you think of a fix?
    noNA <- function(x,y) if(is.na(x)==TRUE|is.na(y)==TRUE){x=0|y=0}else{x|y}
                 TransPnoNA <- mapply(noNA,TransPerSend1[,2],TransPerSend1[,3])

Comment: @VishnuSundaram  I would use something like `t(mapply(function(x,y) {xy <- cbind(x,y); xy[is.na(xy)] <- 0; xy }, TransPerSend1[,2], TransPerSend1[,3]))`.  But, as I said, `mapply` is not adequate for this kind of problem.